# How to fix - Could not find a declaration file for module '@okta/okta-react' - error?

Tags: reactjs, npm, okta

I installed `@okta/okta-react` package in my application but it threw the following error?

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@okta/okta-react'.
'.../node_modules/@okta/okta-react/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/okta__okta-react` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts)
file containing `declare module '@okta/okta-react';`ts(7016)
```

How to fix this error?

What I tried?

I checked this [blog](https://medium.com/@amandeepkochhar/typescript-error-could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-xyz-dfbe6e45c2bd). I tried to implement this solution but my app does not have tsconfig.json.

EDIT 1:

I tried to install `@types/okta__okta-react` but got this error:

```
$ npm install @types/okta__okta-react
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fokta__okta-react - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@types/okta__okta-react@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Comment: Did you try to install the types package - `npm install @types/okta__okta-react` ?

Comment: @Luis Paulo Pinto Yes and I got error. Please see EDIT 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like they do not have types yet. You will need to follow devs advice here https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/issues/66#issuecomment-394574326

Comment: I wrote that advice and it's still valid. We do plan to release TypeScript support for our SDKs soon. A big hurdle was refactoring our underlying Auth JS SDK to support TypeScript. That was completed in our 4.0 release. https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js/releases/tag/okta-auth-js-4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

**Change the node version**

In my case got the [Module not found: Can't resolve] error it got resolved after changing the node version.
previous version = v12.4.0
Updated to = v15.8.0

try nvm use 15.8.0 (in terminal)